# Can reputation mysteriously disappear?

Tags: support, reputation

Last time (about a month ago) when I had come to Chem.SE, my reputation happened to be 342 and I am sure of that figure. As of right now, it has dropped to 332. I really don't know how this has happened. What feels even more interesting is that the reputation tab does not show any changes, neither user deletion, nor downvotes and I am absolutely positive that they have decreased. Has anyone else experienced something like this earlier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You had suggested edits to various questions and answers, and you had gained +2 reputation each time one of your suggested edits had been accepted (see also [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)).

Compared to the situation about one month ago, six of these posts were removed, which resulted in the loss of the corresponding 12 reputation.